# Using QGIS Histogram & Bars for import as GeoJSON polygons

Tags: qgis, geojson, mapbox

I am trying to visualize data as histograms in Mapbox. The way that QGIS displays the same data is perfect, but I can't figure out how to export a file that would render the same effect with JavaScript.

Any ideas?

Comment: Export the raw histogram data and use Javascript plotting to create the histogram. Otherwise you may be stuck with a format that either changes or needs to be changed. A 2-column files is agnostic.